# Custom error message containing parameter names when validation fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey

I would like my API to return errorMessage when the request lacks of required parameters. For example let's say there is a method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{foo}")
public Response doSth(@PathParam("foo") String foo, @NotNull @QueryParam("bar") String bar, @NotNull @QueryParam("baz") String baz)
```

where `@NotNull` is from package `javax.validation.constraints`.

I wrote an exception mapper which looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class Mapper extends ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException) {
    Iterator<ConstraintViolation<?>> it= exception.getConstraintViolations().iterator();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
      ConstraintViolation<?> next = it.next();
      sb.append(next.getPropertyPath().toString()).append(" is null");
    }
    // create errorMessage entity and return it with apropriate status
  }
```

but `next.getPropertyPath().toString()` returns string in format `method_name.arg_no`, f.e. `fooBar.arg1 is null`

**I'd like to receive output `fooBar.baz is null` or simply `baz is null`.**

My solution was to include `-parameters` parameter for javac but to no avail.

Probably I could somehow achieve it with the use of filters:

```
public class Filter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {

    UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();
    UriRoutingContext routingContext = (UriRoutingContext) uriInfo;

    Throwable mappedThrowable = routingContext.getMappedThrowable();

    if (mappedThrowable != null) {
        Method resourceMethod = routingContext.getResourceMethod();
        Parameter[] parameters = resourceMethod.getParameters();

      // somehow transfer these parameters to exceptionMapper (?)
    }
  }
}
```

The only problem with the above idea is that ExeptionMapper is executed first, then the filter is executed. Also I have no idea how could I possibly transfer errorMessage between ExceptionMapper and Filter. Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject [`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) into the exception mapper to get the resource method.

```
@Provider
public class Mapper extends ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        Parameter[] parameters = resourceMethod.getParameters();
    }
}
```